# Hiding read messages in Gmail

Tags: gmail

To unclutter my various email boxes I'd like to hide read messages.  Anyone know how I might do so?  I've tried all I can imagine and no luck.  I'm sure there is an easy answer but not to me!

Answer (score 5):

You have basically three options to view your unread mail.

- First option is to have Gmail sort by unread mail first.  This option does not hide read mail but rather moves it down from the point of prominence.  All unread messages will appear before any other messages.

  1. From your inbox *hover your mouse over* the **Inbox** label and a dropdown arrow will appear to the right (see image).
  2. In the dropdown select **Unread first**.

  [image: Unread first selection]
- Your second option would be to simply use the **is:unread** *search*.  This will show you all unread messages from anywhere in your Gmail.  As you can see in the image below this will show you unread messages from your inbox as well as other labels.

  [image: is:unread search]
- Your final option is more of an addition to the second option.  By *searching* for **is:unread label:inbox** you will only get unread messages that are in your inbox. This will also allow you to view only unread messages in other labels as well if you modify the *label:* portion.

  [image: is:unread label:inbox search]

Answer (score 3):

Just use the view 'Unread Mail' all the time.

You will only see unread mails, and once you read it, it will disappear. You can always go back to the 'real' inbox if you want to see them all.